# Data table not release memory

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have simple function which use some data tables , problem is after execute function memory not release, check memory usage with profiler

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.ToString()))
    {
        //Before 6,920K
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Inventory _INV = new Inventory();
        DataTable _dt1 = _INV.Check_Inventory_Item(textBox1.Text.ToUpper().ToString().Trim());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _dt1;

        DataTable _dt2;
        DataTable _dt3;

        _INV.Check_Balances(textBox1.Text.ToUpper().ToString().Trim(), out _dt2, out _dt3);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = _dt2;
        dataGridView5.DataSource = _dt3;

        dataGridView3.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView4.DataSource = null;

        _dt1.Dispose(); _dt1 = null;
        _dt2.Dispose(); _dt2 = null;
        _dt3.Dispose(); _dt3 = null;

        GC.Collect();
        //After 58,450K
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) to measure memory consumption and to force collection instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are still using your data tables as data sources:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = _dt2;
dataGridView5.DataSource = _dt3;
```

You should not dispose them. Or remove them as datasource first.

Comment: removed as data source not work, `dataGridView2.DataSource = null`